# Why does the native JS FILTER function vary its output

Tags: javascript, filter

I have the following situation using the native JS FILTER function as described.

```
var array = ['hello', 'you', 'hello', 'you', 'hello', 'you', 'hello', 'you', 'hello', 'you', 'hello', 'you', 'hello', 'you', 'hello'];

var regex = new RegExp( "hello", "gi" );

function allMatches( item, index, array ){
  return this.test( item );
}
```

Now run it like this...

```
array.filter( allMatches, regex ).length;
=> 7 // should be 8.
```

**NOTE:** all 8 items that pass into **allMatches** function return true as they should, however the array is missing one item.

Now let's correct the **allMatches** function as described below.

```
 var array = ['hello', 'you', 'hello', 'you', 'hello', 'you', 'hello', 'you', 'hello', 'you', 'hello', 'you', 'hello', 'you', 'hello'];

// NO LONGER USE THIS var regex = new RegExp( "hello", "gi" );

function allMatches( item, index, array ){
  return /hello/gi.test( item );
}
```

Now run as before...

```
array.filter( allMatches ).length;
=> 8 // as it should be.
```

Note the following items in **ALL** examples...

1. Every iteration **THIS** is the regex, as it should be.
2. Every iteration that should be **TRUE** is true, meaning all 8.
3. **THIS** is always the proper regex.

I am not looking for how to make this work, as I know a way to do this. I would like a core understanding as to why this is happening, so that I may avoid the issue in the future.

Here are a few more tries using the following function

```
var regex = new RegExp( "hello", "gi" ); // as before

function allMatches( item, index, array ){
  return this.test( item );
}

array.filter( allMatches, regex ).length;
=> 7 // again, NOT correct.

array.filter( allMatches, /hello/gi ).length;
=> 8 // correct. Passing a regex litteral.

array.filter( allMatches, new RegExp( "hello", "gi" )).length;
=> 8 // correct. Passing the same regexp from
```

> Here is the same non-working example but with a referenced regex literal.
>       var nonConstructorRegex = /hello/gi;

```
array.filter( allMatches, nonConstructorRegex ).length;
=> 7 // NOT correct.
```

NOTE: I thought it had something to do with a passed reference to a regex, but using a referenced regex literal works, where a new RegExp variable built from a constructor does not. See the first item just above.

**UPDATE**

When the result is not correct, it is counting the first **HELLO** as false, which should be **TRUE**.

It seams to occur when the regex value is passed in as a reference. When the regex, either constructed or literal, are passed in no reference is required.

Could it just be timing???

**UPDATE**

After studying the MDN reference from the answer, I understand why.

> Examples
>   Finding successive matches
>
> If your regular expression uses the "g" flag, you can use the exec() method multiple times to find successive matches in the same string. When you do so, the search starts at the substring of str specified by the regular expression's lastIndex property (test() will also advance the lastIndex property). For example, assume you have this script:

```
var myRe = /ab*/g;
var str = 'abbcdefabh';
var myArray;

while ((myArray = myRe.exec(str)) !== null) {
  var msg = 'Found ' + myArray[0] + '. ';
  msg += 'Next match starts at ' + myRe.lastIndex;
  console.log(msg);
}
```

How to test this idea with my example...

```
var array = ['hello', 'hello', 'hello', 'hello'];
var regex = new RegExp( "hello", "gi" );

function allMatches( item, index, array ){
  console.log(this.lastIndex) 
 return this.test( item );
}

array.filter( allMatches, regex ).length;
=> 2.
```

Each iteration would console.log the accumulated position of .lastIndex.

So the first item would result in a .lastIndex of **5** as in position 5 of the string **"hello"**.

The next **hello** would hit, but the .lastIndex would be at position 5. The .test() function would check if the string matches the regex, but at position **5**. This would result in a **0** and thus reset the .lastIndex to 0.

The third iteration would begin at **0** and check that **hello** matches the regex, which it would.

The fourth iteration would then hit, but the .lastIndex would be set at position **5** again, and so we would continue doing this until the end of the array, in this case it is.

Thus...

> IT WAS **COLONEL MUSTARD**, IN THE **COATROOM**, WITH THE "**g**" FLAG!!!

Comment: The root of your problem is the "g" flag. Why are you including it?

Comment: I get 8 instead of 7 for your first example:  http://jsfiddle.net/trfxgcj6/

Comment: Also when I try the first sample, it works fine; the first result has length 8, not 7.

Comment: Run it a second time to see the issue. I didn't realize you also have to run it twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't have much to do with `.filter()`.

When you include the "g" flag on a regular expression, then each call to `.test()` will perform a search of the source string, and if a match is found it will set the value of the `.lastIndex` property on the RegExp object to the index into the source string where the next search should begin.

When you use a regular expression literal in the filter function, that doesn't matter, because each call to the function creates a new RegExp instance. However, when you re-use the regular expression on successive calls, the value of `.lastIndex` will have an effect.

The sample you posted, with an array of strings that alternately match and don't match, won't show any apparent problem. However if you had two `"hello"` strings in a row, then it would, because after matching the first of the pair, the `.lastIndex` value would be 5, so when the `.test()` is called for the next one the search would start at the end of the string and fail.

The bottom line: get rid of the "g" flag.

Comment: Do you happen to have a link I could read up on regarding this detailed behavior? Thanks for explaining. I removed the "g" flag and it works 4.0.

Comment: @SoEzPz [Here's the MDN page for the `.exec()` function, which has the same behavior.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) It's less common to want to exploit the `.lastIndex` behavior with `.test()`.